# How to block progression in a learnr tutorial until the answer to the current chunk is correct?

Tags: learnr

I have set a progressive reveal in my tutorial as detailed [here](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/learnr/articles/exercises.html). This prevents the user from skipping an exercise. The user has to provide an answer but not necessarily a correct one. I would like to use the package gradethis to check the answer and let the user going to the next exercise only if the answer was correct.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for your help,

Here a simple code in the learnr tutorial :

````
---
title: "tutorial"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
````

### Topic 1  {data-progressive=TRUE}

#### Exercise 1

Compute 1 plus 1

```
grade_result(
  pass_if(~identical(.result, 2))
)
```

#### Exercise 2

compute 2 plus 2